# Increment embedded entity property using function style value using Typeorm @createQueryBuilder

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Here is my entity definition

[image]

What I want to achieve is increment

> status.sentCount

on every api call made.

I have gone through documentation and tried to implement the solution for embedded entity
[image]

Although it work for direct field like "age" but doesn't seem to be working for simple-json object "status".

Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with jsonb type data, which you cannot update directly. You can use `jsonb_set` function provided by Postgres.

```js
set(`jsonb_set(status, '{sentCount}', 'new_value')`)
```

I didn't try it but I hope it will work for you.

You can find more info here https://aaronbos.dev/posts/update-json-postgresql

Edited:

Use following query

```
UPDATE your_table SET status = jsonb_set(status, '{sentCount}', (COALESCE(status->>'sentCount','0')::int + 1)::text::jsonb) WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: that didn't work. How can I get hold of previous value? what i wanted to do is status.sentCount += sentCount.

Comment: You can first find the sentCount and then call update to update.

Comment: Yes, I can do so. But what I wanted to do is make one Api call to database. Since, calling await to findOne and then awaiting to save the modified document results in the performance overhead...

Comment: UPDATE your_table 
SET status = jsonb_set(status, '{sentCount}', (COALESCE(status->>'sentCount','0')::int + 1)::text::jsonb)
WHERE id = 1;

can you try this?

Comment: Thanks it did work. However, I have made slight changes to fit my need. Here is my code.


` const query = this.query(
      `UPDATE public.fact
    SET status = jsonb_set(status, '{sentCount}', (COALESCE(status->>'sentCount','0')::int + $1)::text::jsonb)
    WHERE id = $2`,
      [sentCount, id],
    );`

Comment: I am glad it helped you. :)